# Jquery get selected option for dynamic select

Tags: jquery, html

I have an API i'm returning data for it, the data can be added to/removed so hard-coding in different ID's to do the select off of isn't going to work.
What i have is everything in a html table, i append the data from the API call to the table row, there is at most 3 levels for each select "All, "None', "Only"
Everythign is written in HTML/Jquery For the Front end and WebApi C# for the back end

```
$.ajax.....

var HomeTable =$('.HomeBody');
$.each(res.Home function(index,value){
$.each(value, function(id, val){
HomeTable.append(`<tr><td>${value[id].EntityName}</td><td>
<select>
<option>${value[id].InquireLevel[0]</option>
<option>${value[id].InquireLevel[1]</option>
<option>${value[id].InquireLevel[3]</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select>
<option>${value[id].EditLevel[0]</option>
<option>${value[id].EditLevel[1]</option>
<option>${value[id].EditLevel[3]</option>
</select>
</td>
...
```

Anyway to grab the value of the selects without specifying an ID? since there's no real way to know what section the select would apply to as users can delete/add/edit the entity Names.
Each section can have one or more Entities  as well.
Maybe there's a way using the TD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this.
I created an array of Ids and then did the selects based on the values in the array which match the elements render through the each.